# I created a hashing code but it returns the hash for different inputs

Tags: database, sqlite, authentication, tkinter, hash

i was designing a login form. when the user signs up the password is hashed and stored in the database The same user tries to login and the password which is entered om the login form is hashed and compared with the hash in the database but the the login fails saying wrong password.

I tried entering another password different from the first one on the signup page, but the hashes look alike for different passwords

## Login block

```
def handle_connection(self):
    self.username = self.username.get()
    self.password = self.password.get()
    self.password = hashlib.sha256(self.password.encode()).hexdigest()
    conn = sqlite3.connect("userdata.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    root.after(1000,)
    # NUMBER OF ATTEMPTS ALLOWED
    max_attempts = 5
    attempts = 0
    while True:
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", (self.username, self.password))

        if cur.fetchall():
            messagebox.showinfo("Login Successful !")
            break
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Login Failed !", "Wrong password or username !\n Please try again !")
            break
```

## SignUp block

```
def check_sign_up(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("userdata.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    if self.password2.get() == self.password1.get() and self.email.get() != "":
        self.password1 = hashlib.sha256(self.password.get().encode()).hexdigest()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO userdata (username, password, Email) VALUES (?,?,?)",
                    (self.username.get(), self.password1, self.email.get()))
        conn.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("SUCCESS", "Thank you for Joining the Light Technologies")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("E R R O R", "All fields are required !!")
```

Comment: You used `self.password1` and `self.password2` when checking whether they are different, but use `self.password` in generating hash.

Comment: Also you should not overwritten instance variables `self.username`, `self.password` inside `handle_connection()`.

Comment: To identify your issue, it is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo in this line in the SignUp block:

```
self.password1 = hashlib.sha256(self.password.get().encode()).hexdigest()
```

"*but the hashes look alike for different passwords*" because they are all [hashing an empty string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) (I presume).